# Error when running ANN with reccurent layer

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I have created the below ANN with 2 fully connected layers and one recurrent. However when running it i get the error: `Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_11: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` Why is it happening?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.layers import LSTM 




seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("sorted_output.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:15]
scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True ) #data normalization
X = scaler.fit_transform(X) #data normalization
Y = dataset[:,15]
# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=15, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(15, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on above all of layers are "Dense" layers in LSTM you are returning the sequence as true.. You should be setting return_sequences=False because of all Dense layer and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that `LSTM` expects the input to have a shape of 3 dimensions (for batch, sequence length and input dimension). But the `Dense` layer before it outputs a shape of 2 dimensions (for batch and output dimension).

You can see the output shape of the `Dense` layer by executing below lines of code

```
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=15, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
>>> model.summary()
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)                  (None, 12)            192         dense_input_2[0][0]              
====================================================================================================
Total params: 192
Trainable params: 192
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

However, you don't explain your intention with the model, so I cannot give you further guidance for this issue. What is your input data? Do you expect the input to be a sequence?

If your input is a sequence, then I suggest you to remove the first `Dense` layer. But if your input is not a sequence, then I suggest you to remove the `LSTM` layer.